# Parsing errors in Document (see Blender Console)

Tags: import, dae

I recently decided to start modding the game beamng drive and when trying to change the model in blender I got this error: Parsing errors in Document (see Blender Console), but this only happens with one model

after several hours of suffering and searching the Internet for something similar, I decided to open this file using Notpad++ and saw that this model was created using blender version 3.6 and the COLLADA version was 1.4.1

I don’t know what to do next and I ask you for help, link to this model:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aQU9nE5m5iRjyoy255RmnAdmWXAb9zLE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console after trying to import, you will see

```
Schema validation (Error):
Error: ERROR_REQUIRED_ATTRIBUTE_MISSING
Element: texture,
Attribute: texcoord,
Line: 692,
Column: 62
```

Open c35.dae in a text editor and go to line 692. The line is

```
<texture texture="grb1_trunk_light_dds-sampler"/>
```

Change this to

```
<texture texture="grb1_trunk_light_dds-sampler" texcoord="x"/>
```

Save the file and you should now be able to import it.

(Note that the `x` is unimportant, you can put anything there and it will still work.)

This is caused by Blender sometimes failing to write the mandatory `texcoord=` attribute on textures when it exports to Collada. See eg [this bug report](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/58093). I had thought this was fixed...